# How to prove this nice equality, in a setting of cyclic quadrilateral?

Tags: geometry, circles, quadrilateral

Let $ABCD$ be a cyclic quadrilateral.
Let $C'$ be the intersection of $AC$ and $BD$.
Let $B'$ and $D'$ be points on $AB$ and $AD$, respectively, such that $AB'C'D'$ be a parallelogram.
Prove that $$AC.AC' = AB.AB' + AD.AD'.$$

Could somebody give me a hint? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Remember to include your work on the problem. Otherwise it looks like you are trying to get others to do your homework.

Comment: @jjagmath Ah thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I just found two solutions for this problems.

The first one is to use Ptolemy's theorem and notice that $AB'C'$ and $DCB$ are similar.

The second one is to let $E, F$ be points on $AC$ such that $BCEB'$ and $DCFD'$ are cyclic quadrilaterals. Then notice that the middle points of $AC'$ and $EF$ are coincide since $B'ED'F$ is a parallelogram.

Comment: Did you mean $DCFD'$?

Comment: Yes, my typo! I fixed it! thank you.